# How do I remove mold and mildew from subfloor  of a house with crawl space?

Tags: floor, ventilation, mold, crawlspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mold remediation in crawlspace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7834/mold-remediation-in-crawlspace)

House with crawl space has mold and mildew on the sub-floor. I've determined the cause is no vapor barrier and a leaky pipe and there is no structural damage to the wood. I'm installing a vapor barrier and repairing the leaky pipe to stop the moisture source.

**Questions:**

[1] How can I effectively remove the mold and mildew from the sub-floor?

[2] If I stop the source of moisture and provide adequate ventilation to the crawl space, will that be enough to stop the mold growth?

Comment: have you looked at, [Mold remediation in crawlspace](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/7834/3138) & [How to self-remediate mold?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1374/3138), here on SE...

Comment: @Mike.. I was not aware of those two postings. Please close this question since it is a duplicate.